# How to add element on jCarouselLite at runtime?

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousellite

I am having a hard time to achieve this thing. I want to add element on my `ul` on runtime, but this doesn't work properly on jCarouselLite.
When I add `li` element, it just adds at the bottom but not aligned with the flow.

For you to get what I mean, see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/5kMaD/)

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

`jCarouselLite` doesn't appear to support dynamic addition of elements.  You may want to consider using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Dynamic-Content-Loading) instead which does seem to have support for this.

When you add your `li` it is being wrapped onto the next line because `jCarouselLite` has set an explicit width on your `ul` element.  You can stop the `li` from wrapping, by adding to its width as you add the new `li` item:

```
$("#list").width(52 + $("#list").width());
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem because the `jCarousel` object contains a private member variable `itemLength` which is uses to do boundary checking, so it stops before you can get to the end of the Carousel and see the new added item.

You may be able to fudge something by removing + then recreating the Carousel, but it if you need the functionality, it feels like you should try and use a plugin that supports it out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, that was a great explanation. I'm gonna try `jCarousel`

Comment: But is there a way to reload `$("#container").jCarouselLite({})` without refreshing the page? If yes, that could be a solution for me.